# Is there a shorter way of saying "Not knowing what else to do?"

Tags: word-choice, sentence, expression-choice

Does the English language provide a shorter form of the phrase?

Example:

> Not knowing what else to do, I kept walking through the corridor.

Comment: Why would anyone vote to close this great question? How ridiculous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Puzzled', 'undecided', 'confused', etc.

Answer (score 1):

The expression *at wit's end* means exactly not knowing what else to do.

- *at the end of one's ideas or mental resources; perplexed* ([dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/at+ones+wits+end))